# Return a c array from a code, wrapped by cython, to python,

Tags: cython

I am trying to run my C++ code from python, since I want to couple it with an open source software which has python interface, so I used cython for the sake of wrapping . My C++ code can be compiled from python but I have some problems in returning the results which are float vectors. I can return a single float or integer to python but not a vector. I tried to return the pointer, like what is normally done for C++ functions, but python does not recognize the pointer form C++.
here is a simplified code to show what do I mean.

my .hpp file is:

```
#include "mpi.h"

float my_cppfun(int D);
```

my .cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

#include "my_cpp.hpp"


float  my_cppfun(int D)
 {
  float DD[D];
  int i; 
  for (i=0;i<D;i++){
    DD[i]=i;
  }

  return DD[i-1];
  //return DD  instead of DD[i-1]
  }
```

my .pyx file is:

```
cdef extern from "my_cpp.hpp":
    float my_cppfun(int)

def my_cpp(int D):

    return my_cppfun(D)
```

my .py file is:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from pympi import my_cpp

y=my_cpp(3)
print y
```

There is also setup.py file and it is working at the moment. I am wondering how can I return DD array instead of single float value(DD[i-1]). 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you able to give a code example of what you have tried to better help others understand the problem? :)

Comment: Without an example it is quite unclear, what is your problem. Normally Cython automatically converts std::vector into a python-list: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library

Comment: It doesn't seem to be clear to you, that you aren't using c++'s vectors at all. You are using C-arrays.

Comment: this might help. https://gist.github.com/GaelVaroquaux/1249305/3b2990b3f320b95bff91a471ac37c0112951ff10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are going to need to make a list and return that.

The documentation for [List](https://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/list.html?highlight=m) should help. PyList_New, PyList_SetItem, etc.